# Strange behaviour of Parallel Boost Graph Library example code

Tags: c++, boost, parallel-processing, mpi, boost-graph

I have set up simple tests with Parallel Boost Graph Library (PBGL), which I have never used before, and observed entirely unexpected behaviour I would like to explain.

My steps were as follows:

- Dump test data in METIS format (a kind of social graph with 50 mln vertices and 100 mln edges);
- Build modified PBGL example from graph_parallel\example\dijkstra_shortest_paths.cpp

  - Example was slightly extended to proceed with Eager, Crauser and delta-stepping algorithms.

    Note: building of the example required some obscure workaround about the MUTABLE_QUEUE define in crauser_et_al_shortest_paths.hpp (example code is in fact incompatible with the new mutable_queue)

```
    int lookahead = 1;  
    delta_stepping_shortest_paths(g, start, dummy_property_map(), get(vertex_distance, g), get(edge_weight, g), lookahead);  
    dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, start, distance_map(get(vertex_distance, g)).lookahead(lookahead));  
    dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, start, distance_map(get(vertex_distance, g)));
```

- Run

  mpiexec -n 1 mytest.exe mydata.me
  mpiexec -n 2 mytest.exe mydata.me
  mpiexec -n 4 mytest.exe mydata.me
  mpiexec -n 8 mytest.exe mydata.me

The observed behaviour:

- **-n 1**:
  mem usage: 35 GB in 1 running process, which utilizes exactly 1 device thread (processor load 12.5%)
  delta stepping time: about 1 min 20 s
  eager time: about 2 min
  crauser time: about 3 min 20 s.
- **-n 2**: 
  crash in the stage of data load.
- **-n 4**:
  mem usage: 40+ Gb in roughly equal parts in 4 running processes, each of which utilizes exactly 1 device thread
  calculation times are unchanged in the margins of observation error.
- **-n 8**:
  mem usage: 44+ Gb  in roughly equal parts in 8 running processes, each of which utilizes exactly 1 device thread
  calculation times are unchanged in the margins of observation error.

So, except the unapropriate memory usage and very low total performance the only changes I observe when more MPI processes are running are slightly increased total memory consumption and linear rise of processor load.
The fact that initial graph is somehow partitioned between processes (probably by the vertices number ranges) is nevertheless evident.

What is wrong with this test (and, probably, my idea of MPI usage in whole)?

My enviromnent:
- one Win 10 PC with 64 Gb and 8 kernels;
- MS MPI 10.0.12498.5;
- MSVC 2017, toolset 141;
- boost 1.71

N.B. See original example code [here](https://emcl-gitlab.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/hiflow3.org/hiflow3/blob/652128b49e2da45c442d292dc5f611bd245ca893/contrib/boost_libraries/libs/graph_parallel/example/dijkstra_shortest_paths.cpp).

Comment: Is the measured time the elapsed time?

Comment: Yes. Direct measurement with the code like this:  
    if (process_id(process_group(g)) == 0)  
    {  
    cout << "..." << to_simple_string(second_clock::local_time()) << std::endl;  
    }

Comment: So you have some bugs in your code, which you have not shared.  I don't see what you expect people to say?  (I mean, it could also be PBGL, but again your question doesn't help locate the bug).  And it is certainly a bug, as you **crash** at 2 processes.

Comment: As stated above, it's not my code. It's the code of mentioned standard Boost example (path provided), and it is nominally working, but very strange.

Comment: Added a direct link to example to message body.

Comment: Crash in data load stage is the crash of library object in the first meaningful code string of the untouched example, which loads obviously correct format file, which brings no difficulties in the other cases (see link above). It's the second and less interesting question.

Comment: @ВасилийПивоваров Did you compile with ubsan and asan enabled? Do that first. UB can have any result, even if you think the symptoms are less interesting at first. (Nominally working doesn't include the possibility of a crash)

Comment: @sehe Thank you, but as far as I know, there is no such functionality for msvc yet. I considered this problem minor becasue of the distance markup in other cases is stable and valid. It seems that graph is partitioned (by memory-by-process consumption and debug breaks) and the processes communicate "normally" (in some restricted sense), but the times are really awful and wonderfully there is no sign of real algorithm parallelity in them with increasing of n.

Comment: Moreover, I dubt what the beast PBGL delta-stepping really is, because of at my understanding delta-stepping is typical local parallel algorithm for the common memory systems, so it should demonstrate some rate of parallelity even for single process, but it doesn't. Unfortunately, I don't understand the whole bunch of PBGL system architecture here, so I expect that there is some fundamental flaw in my test, not just incorrect build options.

Comment: fatal error: ' boost / graph / distributed / two_bit_color_map.hpp ' file not found I ran into this problem when using this code with boost 1.74 with ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. How did you solve this?

Comment: paste-bin.xyz/39439 
This is the full code with all include headers needed